# d3 Trying to select text within a svg text element

Tags: text, svg, d3.js, getter

I have an SVG text element:

```
<text class="countries" dy="0" dx="-339.87646027037385" font-size="22" style="fill:      #1f77b4;">Afghanistan</text>
```

and all I want to do is to grab the "Afghanistan" text from that on a click event. 
d3.select(this)...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by running

```
var text = d3.select(this).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the click event on your svg Element:

When generating your element you can add a click event using:

```
.on("click", function(){
   // ...
}
```

Does the text you want come out of your data? Then you could do something like:

```
.on("click", function(d){
   window.alert(d.text)
}
```

Hope that helped.